# iOS Push Notification custom sound repeat?

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am working with push notifications. I have implemented custom sound for push notifications.
 Is it possible if push notification custom sound is only 5 sec long then can I repeat it till the max sound limit(30 sec) reach ?

For Example:
Can I play the sound for one notification 6 times repeatedly ?

JSON payload is :

```
array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'blackberry_3.mp3'
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly make the sound repeating.
You have to send another notification to trigger sound another time.

Take a look at this question, that is very similar to yours :
[apple push notification with sound buzzing at regular interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532684/apple-push-notification-with-sound-buzzing-at-regular-interval)