# Is it possible to repeat iOS Notifications with long sound? (Like Apple alarm app.)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to build an iOS app which has a strong notification function in it.

The thing is this notification is not concerned with the time, but the stock market price data. It rings when it matches the preset price of the user.

The notification should have a max long sound and repeatable. When the user checks the notification, it stops like Apple alarm app. Until then, it goes on. (Not just a banner notification with a short sound.)

Is it possible to build this on iOS and how is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Push Notification custom sound repeat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318405/ios-push-notification-custom-sound-repeat)

Comment: No you can't , Need to send Another notification