# Play custom sound when push notification comes and play until user interacts with app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, ios10, ios11

I want to play custom sound in my ios app when a push notification comes and the sound should play unless the user performs some action over the notification otherwise the sound shouldn't stop. I am using swift 3 and ios 10.3+

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30346054/custom-sound-remote-push-notification-ios-not-working/30346466

Comment: The push notification payload can have sound length <= 30 seconds. You can schedule another notification after certain duration to remind the user. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532684/apple-push-notification-with-sound-buzzing-at-regular-interval

Comment: I tried doing this but how can i schedule local notification to be played always if user hasn't interacted with the app.
Means if a push notification comes i can schedule a local notification in didreceiveremoteNotifications but when that local notification comes i have no event to schedule another.

Thanks in advance